# I would like to copy Userform data to the lastrow of A specific range in one column (B) on A worksheet (B13:B37)

Tags: excel, vba

Currently it copies the data into the worksheet starting in cell B13 but copies the data in every row proceeding row 13 in column B I am struggling to find how to limit the LastRow variable to A specific cell range.

```vb
Private Sub AddItem_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Invoice")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("B13:B37" & LastRow + 1).Value = Me.TariffNum.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do, but if you need to populate multiple cells beginning at B3 then `ws.Range("B13:B" & (LastRow + 1)).Value = Me.TariffNum.Text`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the next empty cell in Col B, starting at B13 then:

```vb
Private Sub AddItem_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Invoice")

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row+1
    If LastRow < 13 Then LastRow = 13

    ws.Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = Me.TariffNum.Text

End Sub
```